# cd with variable not working

Tags: bash, cd-command

I am trying to assign a directory name to a variable and use that variable to create and change the directory.

```
dir_name='tmp'
mkdir $dir_name
cd $dir_name
```

How to change directory?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing `bash test.sh` or `./test.sh` creates a child `bash` process to execute your script, with a separate working directory.

You can instead use `source test.sh` or the shorter equivalent `. test.sh` to run the script in the existing bash instance and environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think it works. I followed the following steps.

```
user@ubuntu2004:~$ dirname="snap"
user@ubuntu2004:~$ mkdir $dirname
user@ubuntu2004:~$ cd $dirname
user@ubuntu2004:~/snap$
```